# Directive controller to parent communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The question I am asking is to figure out which is the best practice for communication from the child to the parent controller in a certain scenario. Say for example we have an element with a controller called `"ListController"`, inside which we have a list of directives populated through `ng-repeat`. The directive is linked to a different controller called `"ListItemController"` and has an isolated scope, so can no directly use the functions of the parent `ListController`. In this case with my beginner knowledge of angular I've narrowed it down to 2 options that seem the most intuitive. The first option would be to `$emit` an event in the `ListItemController` and catch it `$on` the `ListController`, but events are commonly considered a poor choice for communication. The second possible option would be to access the parent `ListController` through the use of the `$parent` field of the `ListItemController`, but, assuming because of the fact that our list items are created through `ng-repeat`, we can only reach our `ListController` by using `$scope.$parent.$parent`, which doesn't really smell of good code either. I would like to know which option out of these two or others would be considered the best practice and why?

Comment: you sound like you are trying to develop a component.  A component is a special kind of directive, designed for scenarios like what you are describing, with a specific way to handle interoperability.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: @Claies, following the docs and some other examples I tried making a component to see how it would act, but I ran into some issues with this solution. The scope for a component is always isolated, so calling any functions of the parent controller would, I assume, be as problematic as with a directive. Could you please elaborate how a component would be an optimal solution?

Comment: the final part of the component guide explains Intercomponent Communication;  in fact, they show a parent/child component which is a tab bar with tabs.  the use of `require: { parentCtrl : '^parentCtrl'}` is key.

Comment: @Claies My bad, must have skiped over that part. Correct me if I'm wrong with my final conclusion, but it seems to me that components must have their controllers written alongside them in the same file and are designed for an application structure where everything on the page is a component(and maybe directive)?

Comment: No on both parts.  Components can have their controllers in separate files, as well as have their templates in separate files;  The samples in the documentation show everything in one file for ease of explanation more than anything else.  Components themselves are meant to be self contained, and can be included in an existing app by simply injecting the module for the component into the main app module. (and of course including the relevant files in the project).

Comment: obviously a well designed app is a complete tree of components, but components are modular enough that you can incrementally include them in an existing application structure.